# Datetime and date comparison in django queryset

Tags: django, forms, datetime

Hi I have a user input form which takes date in `2011-05-12` format. I want to query the results using `Q` . But my database field is in datetime format something like `2011-05-18 08:36:34`. I am giving the query like this

`k = Posts.objects.filter(Q(review_email__contains = user), review_time = datetime(date))` where `user` is some username and `date` is the form inputvalue

If I execute the above query I am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can some one help me in solving this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error comes from not doing `datetime.datetime`, but as soon you fix that, you're going run into incorrect results in your query.  When you coerce the `datetime.date` to a `datetime.datetime` object it will be at midnight.  Consequently, only `Posts` created exactly at midnight on that day will match.

You should do this instead:

```
Post.objects.filter(
     review_email__contains = user, 
     review_time__year=date.year, 
     review_time__day=date.day, 
     review_time__month=date.month,
 )
```

See the [queryset reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) for more info.

On a side note, you don't really need to use the `Q` object in this.

Comment: Thanks I got this. I am using Q object for my purpose (for my search criteria)

Answer (score 0):

As, the error says, the *`'module'` object is not callable*. `datetime` is a module. What you want is `datetime.datetime`.

Use:

```
k = Posts.objects.filter(Q(review_email__contains = user), review_time = datetime.datetime(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare the dates, you can try this

> k =
>   Posts.objects.filter(Q(review_email__contains
>   = user), review_time__date = datetime(date).date())